# SOAP Message appearing twice on receiving end

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have a device which will send me data on an interval e.g. 5 minutes. Thus for every data I call the below functions to send data via webservice to the receiving server. All works fine and the only issue the data is appearing twice. I have checked thoroughly for each data I only call once not twice. What else could be issue or need to reset or tweak after sending each data?

```
private static void sendData(String dID,String message) throws Exception {

        try
           {
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
            String url = "http://**********/webservice.asmx?WSDL";
            SOAPMessage soapACK = soapConnection.call(createSOAPIncoming(dID,message), url);
            printSOAPINCOMING(soapACK,message);
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 System.err.println(e.toString());
           }

   }
   private static  SOAPMessage createSOAPIncoming(String dID,String message) throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
         SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
         SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

         String serverURI = "http://*******";

         // SOAP Envelope
         SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
         SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
         SOAPBodyElement element = body.addBodyElement(envelope.createName("receiveData","", "http://*******"));
         element.addChildElement("pt").addTextNode("****");
         element.addChildElement("sn").addTextNode(dID);         
         element.addChildElement("contents").addTextNode(message);
         MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
         headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://********");


         soapMessage.saveChanges();

         /* Print the request message */
         System.out.print("\n\n Request SOAP Message To ACK FOR  = ");
         soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
         System.out.print("\n\n After Print  = ");
         System.out.println();

         return soapMessage;
    }
   private static  void printSOAPINCOMING(SOAPMessage soapResponse,String message) throws Exception {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer1 = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        Source sourceContent1 = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
        System.out.print("\nResponse SOAP Message = \n");
        StreamResult result1 = new StreamResult(System.out);        
        transformer1.transform(sourceContent1, result1);
       //Connection dbconn = null;

       //Statement stat = null;
         //ResultSet rsOC1 = null;
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
        System.out.println("\n\nPrint the soap response:"+ soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent());
      TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();  
      Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();  
      DOMResult result = new DOMResult();  
      transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);  
      Document doc = (Document) result.getNode();

         String tag = "dResponse";

         NodeList list  = doc.getElementsByTagName(tag);
        // String responseTag = itemTitleNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
         Element e = ((Element) list.item(0));
         Element eElement = (Element) e.getChildNodes();

         //System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + e.getNodeName());
         String reponseAnswer = eElement.getElementsByTagName("receiveResult").item(0).getTextContent();
         System.out.println("\nreposne result :" + reponseAnswer);

         if(reponseAnswer.equals("SUCCESS"))
         {




         }


    }
```

Comment: What is this running on, and have you put a debug session on both ends?

Comment: Its running on linux centos. What do you mean by debug session?

Comment: Can you do something like attach a remote debugger on the client and server ends to ensure the message is not being "sent" twice or "received" twice. The setup you provided looks straightforward enough, though I'm not positive why you're creating a new `SOAPConnection` or `MessageFactory` for each call of `sendData(...)`

Comment: The problem is that I cant do anything on the server as we are not allow to manipulate anything. I can only do everything on my end even if need any debugging. So what you suggest how to attach the remote debugger? I am not too sure on this ? If I dont call the Soapconnection each time then how to build the connection?

Comment: You stated that your `sendData(String dID,String message)` call executes every 5 minutes and sends that to the _server_, which would indicate that it's the same URL. So why not keep those objects as class variables? And what I mean by remote debugging would be something like using [Eclipse's remote debug](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.1.v20140609/enable-remote-debugging.html) to set breakpoints on the client to see if anything is happening twice.

Comment: As you suggesting to call the sendData in a separate class?  I cant do Eclipse remote debugging. What I have managed to do is running wireshark. I found there this TCP retransmission what could be the issue that it retransmit?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm suggesting. I'm suggesting that you keep it a class variable and not reconstruct it on every send call. It's needless overhead from what I can see.

Occassional TCP retransmissions are not a problem. TCP is designed to continue going as fast as possible until it suffers packet losses, at which point it slows down until it reaches a stable speed.

Comment: Ok which one do you want me to construct as class variable SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance(); or all other variables too? I would like to confirm is TCP retransmission cause the duplicate message the server end? Any mechanism to avoid ?